# Energy and diligence

Tags: energy

I'm wondering what the best ways to increase mental and physical energy are. I'm often fatigued, and feel slightly lethargic quite often. I have a lot of energy for intellectual tasks, but seemingly, I am fatigued by mundane chores or such things. I also lack willpower for resisting certain tasks.

I believe that a good way to deal with this would be to simply commit to exercising more, but I wonder if there are other ways that Buddhism recommends.

Thank you

Edit: I think my previous post on lying might be relevant. Could it be that integrity--something encompassing effort, willpower, honesty and consistency--be something that I am currently lacking? Something akin to, perhaps, virya? I'm not sure. Any thoughts?

Comment: As I recall, "Sloth and Torpor" are considered a pitfall to overcome. I don't know the sutta where it is addressed, but I am sure you can find by that term. Having energy for "intellectual tasks" is probably either a preference that you have, or egoic energy, which delights in rearranging reality to suit itself (the biggest pitfall). Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

For mental lethargy you can try the techniques to abandon sloth and torpor.

To overcome physical lethargy you can do walking meditation with a quicker pace.